# Optimising thousands of JPanels in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a problem with the optimisation of adding about 4 thousand newly created `JPanel` components to an already existing panel.

The problem is that, surprisingly, it's quite slow. It takes nearly 10 seconds to finish adding them all and that is quite slow for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JMenuItem mntmGenerateRandom = new JMenuItem("Generate random int");
        mntmGenerateRandom.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                for(int i = 0; i < 4000; i++){
                    intPositions.add(rand.nextInt(4000));
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
                quicksort(0, intPositions.size()-1, intPositions);
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                repaintPanels();
                long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("Done in " + (stop-start) + "ms");
            }
        });
}

private void repaintPanels(){
    panelArray.clear();
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
    service.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < intPositions.size(); i++){
                panelArray.add(i, new JPanel());
                panelArray.get(i).setBounds(intPositions.get(i), 1, 1, panelParent.getHeight()-2);
                panelParent.add(panelArray.get(i), 1);
            }
        }
    });
    panelParent.repaint();
    panelParent.revalidate();
}
```

Here's the simplified code, removed everything unnecessary. The slowest part is when I call `panelParent.add(panelArray.get(i), 1);`

Could anyone helped me make it any faster (if it's even possible)?

Comment: `"...4 thousand newly created JPanels"` -- I would re-think this set up. Why would you ever need 4 thousand *containers* which is what a JPanel is for?

Comment: I wonder if what you really want is one single JPanel, one that can paint 4000 or so pixels?

Comment: To sum up, your question is a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is often to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Joop is going to guess at a solution, then so will I.

As I noted in comments a JPanel is typically used as a *container* as a component that holds other components, and you don't appear to be using it to this purpose but rather (to my eyes -- but I'm not 100% sure until you clarify your problem for us), to draw an image. If so, if what you're trying to do is to draw a changing image of blocks or links, one that changes as your sorting algorithm (or whatever you're trying to do in your model) changes, then why not instead use a single drawing JPanel, one whose paintComponent has been overridden, and whose paintComponent draws the state of the model as the model changes. This too is **much** lighter weight than what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It was stupid of me not trying to go for a JPanel with paintComponent overridden. Guess I'll just do that, it'll be much more easier than what I had in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeerdus: you're welcome, but still -- exactly *what* are you trying to create with your program? What is its purpose, and what are you displaying? Also, is there some type animation involved -- changing or evolving image?

Comment: I want to have a JPanel where there's a lot of "lines" which you can edit the properties of, i.e. position, a value they hold, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use a **JTable** instead. It can use one single JComponent child (like a JPanel) to draw all cells, using a CellRenderer and a CellEditor.

This is a *fly weight* pattern, you also might implement yourself: drawing in one single JPanel all "panels."